# fill up NaN values(column1) in existing column based on other column(column2) using pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas

i have 2 columns area and pincode

```
Area Pincode 
ABC - 1234 
XYZ - 4118 
qwe - 1023 
rty - 1234 
XYZ - ? 
rty - ? 
qwe - ? 
ABC - ?
```

so i have multiple areas and want to fillup pincode column based on area as I see area and pin codes are available but i notice that some pin codes are missing though the area is same
Thanks!

```
df4.loc[df4.pins.isnull(),'pins'] = df4.loc[df4.pins.isnull(),'Area'].map(df4.loc[df4.pins.notnull()].set_index('Area')['pins'])
```

but this is not working

Comment: Please add an example of your data (textual not image) along with the code you have tried.

Comment: lets say i have 2 columns area and pincode
Area   Pincode
ABC    1234
XYZ     4118
qwe      1023
rty         1234
XYZ   
qwe
ABC

so i have multiple areas and want to fillup pincode column based on area as I see area and pin codes are available but i notice that no pin code is given through area is same
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!
df4.loc[df4.pins.isnull(),'pins'] = df4.loc[df4.pins.isnull(),'Area'].map(df4.loc[df4.pins.notnull()].set_index('Area')['pins']) but this is not working
Thanks

Comment: show us your sample data and expected output please

Comment: Area Pincode ABC - 1234 XYZ - 4118 qwe - 1023 rty - 1234 XYZ - ? rty - ? qwe - ? ABC - ?  this is my sample data and expected output is i want to fill up missing pincodes of areas as areas are repeating. and I have around 10,000 areas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this *should* work, hard to say without a proper visual of your data..

```
df.loc[df['pcode'].isnull()==True,'pcode'] = df['Unnnamed:']
```

IIUC, you can use a `fillna` with a `groupby` and `transform` to get your result

using your dummy data above : (I replaced your '?' with true null values)

```
   ABC  1234
0  XYZ   4118
1  qwe   1023
2  rty   1234
3  XYZ    NaN
4  rty    NaN
5  qwe    NaN


df['1234'] = df['1234'].fillna(df.groupby('ABC')['1234'].transform('first'))
print(df)
   ABC   1234
0  XYZ   4118
1  qwe   1023
2  rty   1234
3  XYZ   4118
4  rty   1234
5  qwe   1023
```

Comment: lets say i have 2 columns area and pincode
Area   Pincode
ABC    1234
XYZ     4118
qwe      1023
rty         1234
XYZ   
qwe
ABC
so i have multiple areas and want to fillup pincode column based on area as I see area and pin codes are available but i notice that no pin code is given through area is same
Thanks!

Comment: @om9595 please provide a sample input and ouput please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: df['1234'] = df['1234'].fillna(df.groupby('ABC')['1234'].transform('first')) this is working thanks a lot! now my next step is to verify these multiple areas and pin codes with Google's data set ( I have downloaded data set ) but suppose my area Aundh - 411007 and want to verify with Google's data set which says Aaoundh - 411007 which is same but spelling is different so how verify ?

Comment: @om9595 this is a new question, can you accept this one if it answered your query. Ask a new question but read the guide above.

Comment: Sure! Thanks a lot!